# Template literal not working in conjuction with arrow function syntax inside an object?

Tags: javascript, object, arrow-functions

Sorry if this is a silly mistake, I'm rather new to JavaScript.

So I have a key-function pair ('sayHello') inside the object `person` which returns an interpolated string using a template literal (${}). It works fine when I use the standard function syntax.

```
let person = {
  name: 'Ava',
  sayHello () {
    return `Hello, my name is ${this.name}.`;
  }
};

console.log(person.sayHello());
// output: Hello, my name is Ava.
```

However, when I use arrow function syntax with an arrow token, it returns the 'name' value as undefined.

```
let person = {
  name: 'Ava',
  sayHello: () => {
    return `Hello, my name is ${this.name}.`;
  }
};

console.log(person.sayHello());
// output: Hello, my name is undefined
```

Does anyone know what the problem is here, even if it is just a syntax error i've made?

Thanks.

Comment: This is one of the gotchas of arrow functions: they don't have a `this`. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: In your example, `this` is referring to `window` thus returning `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

arrow function expressions are best suited for non-method functions. They don't have `this`. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Description